# Difference between connections in use and threads connected in mysql?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, connection-pooling

Can anyone please tell me what the difference is between the number of connections in use and threads connected to a cluster in MySQL?

I am currently using a single cluster and a pooling library, but intuitively I feel the number of connections and the threads have to be the same as from what I understand one thread has to be spawned for every connection.

However in the metrics, I am observing for my application, I see the number of threads connected is twice the number of connections in use at some points of time, how is this possible?